When I used the Subdivision Surface modifier I get no vertices, edges and faces on the formation

this mess I didnt got vertices, edges and faces. I'm new to 3d softwares. When I used the Subdivision Surface modifier I wanted to make a torso and the edges which are newly formed. I'm not able to see the edges here in betweeen. Can you help please?

hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

You don't have the mirror activated to be edited in edit mode and you are most likely see the mirrored part. Turn on the only Grey icon that you see inside the mirror modifier to make it appear. If that's not the case, you need to give more information

The "newly formed edges" are the edges (vertices and faces) added by the Subdivision Surface modifier and are not directly editable until you Apply that modifier. The only reason that they are viewable is because you have the Optimal Display (Skip displaying interior subdivided edges) option unchecked in the Subdivision modifier panel. Viewable but not editable.
see gif below:

To Apply the modifier, Object mode > open the little drop-down menu in the top bar of the modifier and choose the Apply option.
Now back in Edit mode you able to edit all the extra geometry created by the Subdivision modifier.


I am just started learning thank you.... for the answer it was a stupid question !! sorry!!

@Vishesh Tomar if the answer is correct, mark it as such
